# Laravel | botão visível apenas para administrador

Tags: php, laravel, view

Estou aqui com uma pequena dificuldade em colocar uma regra em que um botão apenas fica visível para utilizadores em que o seu nível seja "administrador".

```
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">
          <i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>
          <p>
            Registo Utilizador
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
```

estou a tentar colocar da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
          if ($nivel_utilizador == 'admin'){

      echo '<li class="nav-item">'
     echo   '<a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">'
     echo     '<i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>'
     echo       '<p>'
     echo        'Registo Utilizador'
     echo       '</p>'
     echo   '</a>'
     echo '</li>'

          }
```

o único em que estou a ter problemas, pois dá-me erro é na seguinte linha :

```
echo   '<a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">'
```

Comment: Não sei se vai ajudar, mais aqui na documentação explica algumas formas de como isso pode ser possível: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#authentication-directives

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as diretivas do Laravel nas views blade, ficando assim:

```
 @if($nivel_utilizador == 'admin')
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">
      <i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>
      <p>
        Registo Utilizador
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
 @endif
```

se quiser se aprofundar mais e aprender sobre as diretivas vou deixar um link da documentação do laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#blade-directives

Answer (score -2):

Provavelmente você está tendo erro por não escapar ' e " corretamente. Para o código ficar mais fácil utilize o if dessa forma:

```
<?php  if ($nivel_utilizador == 'admin') : ?>

<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">
     <i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>
     <p>
       Registo Utilizador
     </p>
  </a>
</li>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

Não sei em que nível de desenvolvimento sua aplicação está, mas recomendo fortemente o pacote [spatie/laravel-permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction). Este pacote vai facilitar nos papéis e permissões do sistema.

Após instalado e configurado, você poderá fazer algo como:

```
@can('view-registro')
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>
            <p>Registo Utilizador</p>
        </a>
    </li>
@endcan
```

ou

```
@role('admin')
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>
            <p>Registo Utilizador</p>
        </a>
    </li>
@endrole
```

A documentação do pacote está em: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction

O repositório do pacote está em: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission